# Does OpenCV have a function like circshift from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, opencv

In the Matlab code, I used [circshift](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/circshift.html) function, does OpenCV have a function similar to circshift in Matlab?

Comment: This seems very easy to do with som indexing and modulo operations

Comment: perhaps you could describe what circshift does and people might be able to help?

Comment: @LuisMendo except that would lose much of the performance advantage of OpenCV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not implemented in the code-base yet, but someone has submitted a [version](http://code.opencv.org/issues/2299). There is a download link to `shift.hpp` file.

For OpenCV 3.1 change includes to:

```
#include <limits>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
```

Comment: this is deadlink